Android "forgets" Ionic LiveUpdate version
I am using Ionic AppFlow, with its LiveUpdate functionality.
As default my app listens to the Production channel for updates from Appflow. Then I have implemented a feature so that my QA person can tap a button, and download and install which ever build I have assigned to the BETA channel. This works very well, until the QA person leaves the app idle, or restarts it. On iOS it seems to be OK, but on Android it looks like it "forgets" what was installed from the BETA channel, and reverts to either what was in the original binary or what ever is available on the Production channel.
I can't find any reason for this, nor a solution. Is there anyone who has seen the same behavior and can point me in the right direction here?
Thanks in advance!
